# Shell Script for removing craskernel

Tags: linux, shell

How can I remove `crashkernel` parameter and attached value from `grub.conf` ?

```
title RHELOS (3.6.18-274)
        root (hd0,0)
        kernel /vmlinuz-3.6.18-274 ro root=LABEL=/ nmi_watchdog=1 crashkernel=64M@16M rhgb quiet console=tty12 loglevel=1
        initrd /initrd-3.6.18-274.img
```

to

```
    title RHELOS (3.6.18-274)
        root (hd0,0)
        kernel /vmlinuz-3.6.18-274 ro root=LABEL=/ nmi_watchdog=1 rhgb quiet  
        console=tty12 loglevel=1
        initrd /initrd-3.6.18-274.img
```

Tried `awk` method but it deletes the entire line.

Just the parameter `crashkernel` and not entire line.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Using sed:

```
sed -i 's/crashkernel=[0-9@M]*[ ]*//' gryb.conf
```

or,

```
sed -i 's/crashkernel=[^ ]*[ ]*//' gryb.conf
```

Comment: Thanks ! First one does not work and second one I did not try it 
but found another solution
grubby --update-kernel="$(grubby --default-kernel)" --remove-args="crashkernel"

Answer (score 0):

```
  grubby --update-kernel="$(grubby --default-kernel)" --remove-args="crashkernel"
```